# Optimize an Union query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, union

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 78 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
    union
    SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 795 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
    union
    SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 56 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
    union
    SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 89 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
    union
    SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 90 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
```

here 78,795,56,89,90 are the set of account IDs for the condition ,if number of IDs increases that much union i need to add

Anyone help me to Optimize this query to better way

Comment: Yes - get rid of the UNIONs!!

Comment: If I get this straight, you will have a row that is the sum of all amounts that are NOT in account 78, then a sum of all amounts that are not in account 795, and so on. I think it will be easier to get the amounts that ARE in each account with a simple group aggregation, then also get the total of all accounts, and subtract for each one.

Comment: Sanity check: Consider account 100. For every `journaltransaction` for AccountID=100 you will have a row containing the `ID`, `isDebit` and `AccountID` (100 in this case) of that transaction, and and the `SUM` of all amounts not in AccountID=78. That is for just the first unioned query. For the second, have `ID`, `isDebit`, `AccountID`=100, are all identical to the first query's results, but now with a different `Amount` value, which excludes AccountID=795, not 79. Other than the `Amount` value being different, the rows are the same. Repeat for every `AccountID`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Huh?  A `SUM()` plus some other columns, but no `GROUP BY`??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID NOT IN (78,795,56,89,90) and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'
```

Note: Since you have use `SUM` in your SQL,you need to use `GROUP BY` to get the desired result

---

For your quesiton,try with below,in this case,we get the id from another same tab le and then use `<>` to get the result

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, a.isDebit, a.AccountID, SUM(a.Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions a
    JOIN journaltransactions b ON b.id IN (78,795,56,89,90);
WHERE
    BETWEEN '2018-11-29' AND '2018-11-29'
    AND a.id<>b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your remarks.;if union use i get data's number of row equals number of Ids.And also when **AccountID <>78** case i need sum of amount include Account having ID of 795,56,89,90 and other IDs too.i think if we use **not in** it will exclude 795,56,89,90..

Comment: @rahuLrajaN Seems you can use `GROUP BY id` at the end of it

Comment: Ok. problem with number of row solved,but In case of **AccountID<>78** while calculating the amount sum the query excluded the amount of **AccountID include 795,56,89,90** while **using not in**

Comment: @rahuLrajaN Then I think you need to use a temp table or use a foreach to do it

Comment: Do you have any sample of foreach in mysql or any reference

Comment: It's not working have you any idea to iterate below query with foreach loop in procedure    **SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID <> 78 and date between '2018-11-29' and '2018-11-29'** with **set of AccountID (795,56,89,90)**

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. I've left out the SUM because it's not exactly clear what should be summed.

```
SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
   AccountID NOT IN (78,795,56,89,90) 
   and date = '2018-11-29'
```

Comment: it calculate sum of transaction amount of account not equal to each account IDs,Suppose take **AccountID<>78** the amount is calculated by summing all **Account exclude AccountID=78**

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query, and adjust your question accordingly